# socket.io is getting error: "Unexpected token ..."

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am starting with socket.io, and while following [their tutorial](https://socket.io/get-started/chat/) I had encountered the following error message:

```
/path/to/my/app/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket.js:347
      ...options
      ^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...
    at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:549:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:586:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:494:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:453:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:445:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:504:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/path/to/my/app/node_modules/ws/index.js:3:19)
```

This is my index.js:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('a user connected');
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

Have node installed, express and socket.io. Everything worked fine until this step on the tutorial. If I remove **io** variable it start running again.

Searched on google for the same error, but couldnt find anything.

Answer (score 10):

Seems like I found the answer. I will post here for other people having the same problem.
After keep looking for an answer I found this link:

https://github.com/uport-project/uport-cli-client/issues/2

The user Zachferland answers the OP question about the ellipsis (...) error.

> @KamesCG thanks for the issue! yeah it seems the object spread
>   operator was not supported in node until 8.2.1 (with flag, and then
>   8.6.0). To try it right now, run a greater version of node, and in the future we will update uport-js-client to transpile the src for wider
>   node version support.

Then I checked my node version:

```
[root@localhost test]# node -v
v6.17.1
```

Which answer my question. When I installed nodejs, I just run

```
yum install nodejs -y
```

Which installed the old version. Seem like you have to update yum rep. In my case I have a CentOS7 server. I think apt have the same problem.

After following [this tutorial](https://tecadmin.net/install-latest-nodejs-and-npm-on-centos/), everything worked fine.

To summarize, I ran the following, according to the link:

```
yum install -y gcc-c++ make
curl -sL https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo yum install nodejs
```

Comment: For it to work for me I had to uninstall my old version of node first before.

Comment: sudo yum erase nodejs to remove node.js